# would redux trigger re render if a nested property is updated?

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-context

```
export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    info: {
      dob: null,
    }
  }
})
```

What if the `dob` property is updated but the reference that `info` is pointing to is not changed? Would this cause a component which depends on `user.info.dob` to re render?

Comment: No, you have to modify the reference of `info`  as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the data type.
If it is primitive - (number, string) yes

If its an object, then you have to reference (point to another object).
It can be as simple as `{... prevObject, newProperties }`

But deeply nested can make life miserable. So using a library called Immer is recommended (https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/choosing-the-state-structure)